# Is there a way to disable the use of certain blocks on a minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-bukkit

I have a bukkit server I run that is based on the latest version.

I have loaded a few mods mainly buildcraft, IC2, forestry and the BC-IC2 crossover.

Everything seems to be working fine but there is one thing that is bugging me. Forestry adds an electrial engine so you power it with IC2. Well so does the crossover mod (4 actually). What I want to do is "disable" the use of the electrical engine from forestry as in I don't want it show up or be spawnable even through commands.

How could I do this? Just give it no block id? or is there more to it?

Comment: I'm sure there's a plugin for this, but my quick cursory search didn't turn anything up.  Perhaps you could check the bukkit forums.

Comment: I will do that, I thought of starting here any maybe getting answer in a few hours rather than a few days.

Comment: I was actually just suggesting a search to start off with.  SE exists because forums suck for Q&A.  But forums are good for posting about new/updated mods and the such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes** - using [WorldGuard](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldGuard)

You can [set up a blacklist](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldGuard/Blacklist) with very fine detail, for example:

```
[goldore,ironore]
ignore-groups=admins
on-break=deny,tell,notify

[tnt]
ignore-groups=admins
on-place=deny,notify,kick
```

As with WorldEdit, you can use block ids in place of names, and you can use the `on-acquire` trigger to notify players when they attempt to craft the item.

Comment: That is really cool, but I am looking more to make it not even an option at all. I was even wanting to reuse its block id for something else.

Comment: If you want to do that you're going to have to recompile the mod without that block, sorry.

Comment: Oh I see, well that would be a problem. Thanks for the help.